# How to redirect after form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to set up a redirect after my form validation script runs. But when I click submit it throws my requires a valid email error and then redirects skipping my validation checks.

Currently I've tried adding the function in at the bottom of my js file. But it redirects with out running the validations.

```
HTML
<button class="popup-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>
<div class="form-popup" id="form">
<form id="form" onsubmit="return formValidate(event)">
<p>
<input type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Email" />
</p><p>
<input type="password" id="pswd" placeholder="Password" />
</p>
<br>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" class="submit" 
onclick="redirect()">
 <br>
<button type="button" class="btn cancel" 
onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
</form>

JS
  function formValidate(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var email = document.getElementById('e-mail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('pswd').value;

var emailRGEX = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

var emailResult = emailRGEX.test(email);
//validate Email
if(emailResult == false){
alert("Please enter a valid email address");
return false;
}

//validate lower case
var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
if(password.match(lowerCaseLetters) == null) {
  alert("Password needs a lower case!");
  return false;
}

//validate upper case
var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
if(password.match(upperCaseLetters) == null){
  alert("Password needs an upper case!");
  return false;
}

//validate numbers
var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
if(password.match(numbers) == null){
  alert("Password needs a number!");
  return false;
}
//validate special characters
 var special = /[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g;
 if(password.match(special) == null){
alert("Password needs a special character!");
return false;
}
 //validate password length
 if(password.length<8) {
alert("Password needs to be at least 8 characters");
return false;
}

form.submit();

 }
function redirect(){
window.location.href="thankyou.html";
}
```

I expect the form to redirect to my thankyou.html page after running the validation checks.

Comment: **Answer removed** after noticing you have bigger problems. Your first issue is that you aren't actually calling the `formValidate()` function anywhere in your code. Secondly, if you submit the form, the page will refresh and the `redirect()` function will not be called. You'll need a conditional check in the code above to see if the form has been submitted successfully before you can redirect.

Comment: @AndrewDaly - Please migrate your comment into an answer as it deserves selection as correct answer and any upvotes it might also garner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the redirect in the validation function before form.submit

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function validateForm() {
 var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
 if (x == "") {
alert("Name must be filled out");
return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="b.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please find the given example.

And make sure that your b.html is also in same folder. If you want to call another html from javascript then use window.location.href = url; after successful validation.

Hope this will help you. Thank you